# Type Mismatch with Excel VBA script intended to autoupdate when user changes cell

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

After looking at various sources on the web, I've pieced together an excel script designed to act as a log every time a user updates a cell (notes). It basically creates a running list of changes, without duplicates, for tracking updates to projects/etc. Below is the script. It worked well initially, but suddenly it has started giving me Runtime Error '13' messages about a type mismatch at the following line `Set rng1 = Range(Sheet3.Cells(rng2.Row, 2), Sheet3.Cells(rng2.Row, 2).End(xlDown)).Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)`, and I can't figure out why it's suddenly failing. I'm a novice with VBA, so help would be appreciated.

```
    Sub UpdateNotes()

    Dim lngLastRow As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim newRow As Integer
    Dim nextRow As Integer
    Dim lngLastRow1 As Long


    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range

    lngLastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    n = lngLastRow

    For i = 2 To n


        strSearch = Sheet1.Cells(i, 10).Value
        strSearch1 = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value



        Set rng2 = Sheet3.Range("A:A").Find(strSearch1, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then

        Set rng1 = Range(Sheet3.Cells(rng2.Row, 2), Sheet3.Cells(rng2.Row, 2).End(xlDown)).Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)


        Set rng3 = Range(Sheet3.Cells(rng2.Row, [2]), Sheet3.Cells(rng2.Row, [2]).End(xlDown))

        nextRow = rng3.Rows.Count + rng2.Row

        Sheet3.Cells(nextRow, 1).EntireRow.Insert

        Sheet3.Cells(nextRow, [2]).Value = Sheet1.Cells([i], [10]).Value
        Sheet3.Cells(nextRow, 1).Value = Date
        Sheet3.Cells(nextRow, 1).Font.Bold = False
        Sheet3.Cells(nextRow, [2]).Font.Bold = False

    End If

    Else

    MsgBox "Not working..." & strSearch1

    End If

    Next i

    End Sub
```

ETA: After some debugging, it appears the error goes away if I remove multiple simultaneous instances of updated notes (aka, various rows that appeared to be changed simultaneously without the update script running). I'm not sure why it would cause this error, but when I removed the multiple unprocessed updates and retyped them one-by-one, the program works as intended. Thoughts on the underlying cause so I can easily avoid this going forward?

Comment: Run through the code manually line by line, using F8. As you go through, hover over the variables you are using. Does one of them pop up a value you wouldn't expect? Perhaps if rng2 is an error, then it is "not nothing", and then when you set rng1 = something based on rng2, it breaks.

Comment: When the code crashed, I entered debug mode and hovered over the variables. Nothing stood out as being incorrect as far as i could tell. I then ran the sub line-by-line, as you suggested, and went through several iterations of the for loop with nothing looking strange/etc. (didn't have time to go through each iteration yet to the point where it was initially crashing). I'll report back once i get time to go through the entire loop one step at a time.

Comment: If you are debugging code with a for loop, you can instert a stop inside of an if statement which you expect to be hit at a specific moment. ie: if you have a for i = 1 to 10 loop, and you want to see the variables when i = 6, add a statement inside the loop that says 'if i = 6...' then add a stop to that line. Then you can hit play and it will pause when i = 6.

Comment: I actually wanted to run through the iterations (not many in my case) to help determine what was changing to cause it to fail. Interestingly enough, I found that the iteration that it failed would change if I altered the notes for that specific row. I've now come to the conclusion that this error must have been caused by a previous failed update attempt, which allowed the user to make several changes to various rows without it updating. I'm not sure why it caused this error, but when I removed/retyped all of the previously unprocessed notes (one-by-one) the program started working again.

Comment: Okay, so I spoke too soon. Getting the error again, despite only having one field that needs updating (which makes sense, given that nothing in my code should obviously fail from multiple updates). Still unsure of the root cause...

Comment: Try the debugging again, as I mention above. When the line gets to the value in the FOR loop which has the error, what do the surrounding variables say?

Comment: Values look correct for all variables. However, I noticed a new error that I corrected; there were duplicate entries in the log immediately preceding the log entry where the code was crashing. I removed duplicates and ran the script again and it worked fine. Will continue testing to see if this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For your ranges, I would suggest using "with", to explicitly tell the Range what sheet to use:

```
Sub UpdateNotes()

    Dim lngLastRow    As Integer
Dim n             As Integer
Dim i             As Integer
Dim newRow        As Integer
Dim nextRow       As Integer
Dim lngLastRow1 As Long, strSearch As String, strSearch1 As String
Dim rng1          As Range
Dim rng2          As Range
Dim rng3          As Range
Dim sht1          As Worksheet
Dim sht3          As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sht3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

lngLastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

n = lngLastRow

For i = 2 To n

    With sht1
        strSearch = .Cells(i, 10).Value
        strSearch1 = .Cells(i, 3).Value
    End With

    With sht3
        Set rng2 = .Range("A:A").Find(strSearch1, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
            Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(rng2.Row, 2), .Cells(rng2.Row, 2).End(xlDown)).Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)

            Set rng3 = .Range(.Cells(rng2.Row, [2]), .Cells(rng2.Row, [2]).End(xlDown))

            nextRow = rng3.Rows.Count + rng2.Row

            .Cells(nextRow, 1).EntireRow.Insert

            .Cells(nextRow, [2]).Value = sht1.Cells([i], [10]).Value
            .Cells(nextRow, 1).Value = Date
            .Cells(nextRow, 1).Font.Bold = False
            .Cells(nextRow, [2]).Font.Bold = False
        Else
            MsgBox "Not working..." & strSearch1
        End If
    End With

Next i

    End Sub
```

Or, more directly, change your ranges to `Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(rng2.Row, [2]), Sheet3.Cells(rng2.Row, [2]).End(xlDown))`.

Does that do anything? Or still throw errors?

Edit: AFAIK, you didn't define "Sheet1", and VBA (I believe) doesn't have a "Sheet1" built in.  You either can do Sheets("Sheet1"), or Sheets(1) using the index.  I have set the sheets to a variable (change their name as needed), and used that to define the ranges.  Should be okay now.

Comment: Both of these suggestions produce the same error, so not the source of the problem.

Comment: Hmm.  Did you try @Grade'EhBacon's advice?

Comment: Aha!! Did you ever define "Sheet3"?? See my edited answer above, I think I may have got it.